# update multiple rows from different table sqlite3

Tags: sqlite

I want to update rows of table from another table based on a common key using sqlite3.
Here are  my tables.

table1 structure.

```
id name common_key
1       10
2       20
3       30
```

table2 structure.

```
id  name common_key
11   a    30
12   b    10
13   c    20
```

After updating table1 should be like below.

```
id  name common_key
1   b    10
2   c    20
3   a    30
```

I want to write a single query to update name of table1 from table2 where common_key's match.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can't use `JOIN` with `UPDATE` in `sqlite` like `mysql` and `sql-sever` etc..
But we can achieve it with by using sub-query.

**Query**

```
update table1
set name = (
    select name from table2
    where common_key = table1.common_key
);
```

**Example**

[image]

Comment: If this helps, please mark this as answer